# When did lord Vishnu kill sage Bhrigus wife?Was it after Samudramanthan? And when did Sage Bhrigu kick Lord Vishnu?Please Explain chronological order

Tags: vishnu, asuras, vedic-gods, curse, bhrigu

[What is the story of Sage Bhrigu testing Lord Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14065/what-is-the-story-of-sage-bhrigu-testing-lord-brahma-vishnu-and-shiva)

[What is the story of Vishnu killing sage Bhrighu's wife Kavyamata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/what-is-the-story-of-vishnu-killing-sage-bhrighus-wife-kavyamata)