# What is the story of Shankchood? Was he an incarnation of Lord Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, vaishnavism, rebirth

Some people are spreading stories (online) about Shankhchud being an icnarnation of Visnu.
Quote 1:

> There was a demon named Dambh. He prayed to Lord Vishnu because he wanted Vishnu as his son. A partial incarnation of Vishnu was born as Dambh's son. His name was Shankhchud. This Shankhchud was Sudama of Golok who had been born on Earth because of a curse by Radha.

Source 1: http://www.india-forums.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=679859

Quote 2:

> Omniscient Lord Vishnu then addressed his wives-“My dear auspicious Lakshmi! You go to earth and take birth as daughter of king Dharmadhwaj. You will be the wife of demon Shankhchood who is my partial incarnation and then will also assume the form of tree as preordained. Later on, you will join me back and will be worshipped on earth as plant of Tulasi. As cursed by Saraswati, you will flow as river Padmavati on earth. Ganga! You too will flow as river on earth as cursed by Saraswati….

Source 2: http://shrikrishnthesuprememan.blogspot.com/2014/04/the-sweetheart-of-lord-srikrishn.html

Comment: "This Shankhchud was Sudama of Golok who had been born on Earth because of a curse by Radha" - This is from Shiv Purana - RUDRA SAMHITA - YUDH KHAND ...by this way, he might be an incarnation of Sudama and not of Vishnu...

Comment: But their are two sources and quotes not one. Both of them still talk of him as an incarnation of Visnu. By the way it's interesting how you appear everywhere. But is their a link to Shiva Purana?

Comment: Jalandhar & shankhchuda's story was somehow similar in their climax. Chastity of both person's wives are broken by Vishnu as per puranic stories.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments **Shankhchuda was an incarnation of Sudama not Vishnu.** The **[Shiv Purana](http://hinduonline.co/Scriptures/Puranas/ShivaMahaPurana.html)** section 1.2.130 in the shared link mentions the following story:

> 1.2.130 Birth of Shankhachuda - Sutji narrated the tale of the birth of Shankhachuda and how Shiva killed him with his Trishula. **He told the sages that Shankhachuda was born to the demon king 'Dambha'. Shankhachuda was in fact, Sudama, in his previous life. He was born in the family of demons due to the curse of Radha.**
>
> 1.2.131 Shankhachuda’s Marriage - When Shankhachuda grew up, he went to Pushkar and did a tremendous penance to please lord Brahma. Lord Brahma blessed him and said that he would remain invincible. He also instructed Shankhachuda to go to 'Badrikashram' where he would find his would be **wife Tulsi- the daughter of Dharmadhwaja.** Shankhachuda went to Badrikasharam and married Tulsi as per the instructions of lord Brahma. He then returned back to his capital accompanied by his wife- Tulsi.

The rest of the story goes as follows:

> 1.2.132 **Shankhachuda Becomes the Ruler of All Three Worlds** - When Shankhachuda reached his capital after marrying Tulsi, he was crowned as the king of the demons by Shukracharya. After his coronation, Shankhachuda attacked Indrapuri supported by his huge army and defeated the deities. In a very short time all the three worlds were under his control. After being defeated by Shankhachuda, the deities went to lord Brahma and sought his help in eliminating the menance called Shankhachuda. Lord Brahma then took them to lord Vishnu. All of them were taken to lord Shiva by Vishnuji. They expressed their request to liberate them from the troubles created by Shankhachuda.
>
> 1.2.133 **Shiva Assures the Deities** - Lord Shiva assured the deities that he will certainly kill Shankhachuda and hence they should not worry about him. The deities then happily returned to their respective abodes.
>
> 1.2.134 **Conversation Between Pushpadant & Shankhachuda** - Lord Shiva sent his messenger named Pushpadant, to Shankhachuda to ask him to return back the kingdom of the deities to them. Shankhachuda refused to oblige this demand, on the contrary he expressed his willingness and readiness to fight lord Shiva. Pushpadant returned back and narrated the whole story to lord Shiva.
>
> 1.2.135 **Shiva Proceeds with his Army** - Lord Shiva was now fully convinced about the inevitability of the battle. He first sent all his ganas under the leadership of **Kartekiye and Ganesha. Later on Bhadrakali proceeded towards the battlefield** with a huge army as per the own wish of lord Shiva himself. At last lord Shiva proceeded towards the battlefield accompanied by the deities. All the troops collected at the bank of river Chandrabhaga and rested under the shade of a Banyan tree.
>
> 1.2.136 **Shankhachuda Proceeds with his Army** - Shankhachuda handed over the kingdom to his son and went to his wife to take her permission before going to the battlefield. His wife was reluctant to allow him to go, but he somehow managed to convince her. He then proceeded towards the banks of Chandrabhaga with a huge army.
>
> 1.2.137 **Battle Between the Deities and the Demons** - A fierce battle started between the deities and the demons. Both of them attacked each other with the most destructive weapons. But when the army of Chandrachuda began to dominate the fight, the deities fled away and took the refuge of lord Shiva. They told Shiva of the number of deities who had been killed while fighting.
>
> 1.2.138 **The Battle Between Shiva’s Family & Shankhachuda** - After the defeat of the deities and the ganas Kartikeya and Ganesha went to fight Shankhachuda. A spectacular battle was fought between Shankhachuda and both of them. Later on they were joined by Bhadrakali. Bhadrakali would have devoured Shankhachuda without any problem, but she spared his life because of the boon, given to him by Lord Brahma. Now it was the turn of Lord Shiva to join the battle, but even he could not cause any harm to him because of lord Brahma's boon.
>
> 1.2.139 **Strategy Employed to Kill Shankhachuda** - While a tremendous battle was being fought between lord Shiva and Shankhachuda. Lord Vishnu appeared and demanded the armour from Shankhachuda, which he had put on, his body in the guise of a brahmin. Shankhachuda gave his armour to him without any kind of suspicion. Lord Vishnu then went to Shankhachuda's wife in the guise of her husband i.e. Shankhachuda. He destroyed the chastity of Tulsi - Shankhachuda's wife. Shankhachuda derived his power from the chastity of his wife and it vanished the moment, her chastity was destroyed.
>
> 1.2.140 **Lord Shiva Kills Shankhachuda** - Bhadrakali was creating havoc in the army of Shankhachuda. Shankhachuda became very furious and attacked Shiva. Shiva repulsed his assault and attacked him with his Trishul. Shankhachuda who had became powerless was killed instantaneously. The deities were very pleased at the death of Shankhachuda. After worshipping lord Shiva they went back to their respective abodes.
>
> 1.2.141 **Tulsi Curses Lord Vishnu** - After being instructed by goddess Parvati, Lord Vishnu had gone to Tulsi in the guise of her husband- Shankhachuda, so that the breach of Tulsi chastity could help lord Shiva to kill Shankhachuda, who derived his power from Tulsi's chastity and virtuosity.
>
> Initially Tulsi could not recognize lord Vishnu. She was extremely joyous at his arrival. But very soon she was able to realize the real identity of lord Vishnu, who had disguised himself as her husband. She became very angry and cursed lord Vishnu to become a stone. She was crying unconsolably. Lord Vishnu contemplated on Shiva as a result of which he appeared. Lord Shiva blessed Tulsi that she would become the beloved of Lord Vishnu.
>
> **Due to Tulsi's curse, Lord Vishnu attained the form of Shaligram which is a stone and because of lord Shiva's blessings. Tulsi leaves started being offered to the Shaligram, in the process of its worship.**

That my friend is the complete story of Shankhachuda as per the Shiva Purana.

Comment: When it exactly happened because SudAmA was there around 3501 BC.

Comment: Ok thank you sir. But i'm still confused on why the quotes called him "a partial incarnation of Vishnu"?

Comment: My pleasure. It may be an attempt to justify Lord Vishnu cohabiting with Tulasi.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker See, earlier when Saraswati and Ganga fought, then Saraswati cursed Lakshmi for stopping her saying- "**You will become a river and tree.**" So Lakshmi became a river Padmavati. And later became daughter of DharmaDhwaja named "Tulasi" who became the Tulasi tree(or plant whatever). Then once, Sudama was attracted by Tulasi Gopi in Goloka. Krishna had enjoyed Tulasi after a Raasa, so Radha cursed her saying "**You will be a tree**". Sudama screamed at Radha for this curse, so Radha cursed Sudama saying "**You will be born as a demon**". Then Krishna came ........

Comment: ....and calmed Radha. Then Krishna resolved the matter by saying "**O Tulasi you go to mortal world and become daughter of DharmaDhwaja. Sudama who is born of my Parts will become a demon and marry you.**"........ Now see that Tulasi was a Gopi who came out of Radha as part incarnate, and Radha and Lakshmi are same, so in this way **Lakshmi , in part incarnation became a tree Tulasi.** Also, Krishna himself said **Sudama is my Parts**, this is why ShankhaChuuda is part incarnation of Vishnu. This all story is in three- **Devi Bhagawatam, Shiva Puraana and Brahma Vaivarta Puraana**. @knowledge

Comment: @KnowlegeSeeker also Dambha Asura had done Tapas for Krishna to get a son. Krishna appeared and blessed Dambha by saying **"A son will be born to you of my Parts."** This son was ShankhaChuuda who was Sudama (again born of Krishna's parts). This is how Sudama took birth as ShankhaChuuda. Again- Devi Bhagawatam, Shiva Purana and Brahma Vaivarta.

Comment: @AnuragSingh thanks for filling in the gaps :)

Comment: So killing shankhchuda was the reason behind that the use of shank (conch shell) was prohibited in the worship of lord Shiva?

Comment: @aniketkumarsingh possible.. thats an interesting connection.