# Why God Shiva used trident on Kashyapa's son? and why could not he save his own son (Ganesha) from curse?

Tags: shiva, ganesha, curse

Kashyapa cursed Shiva:

"Just as you pierced my son's chest with a trident, your son's head will be chopped off one day," said Kashyapa.

My question is, Why God Shiva used trident on Kashyapa's son? and why couldn't he save his own son (Ganesh) from curse?

Even god shiva can't escape from Kashyapa's curse?

Comment: your Q is duplicate of 2/3 Questions: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3704/12304 https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7620/12304 https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19251/12304 (answer contains details on it).. i think Mods can mark a Q as duplicate of multiple Qs...

Comment: unknown person destroy my questions with 3 different once and make it duplicate.. fair?

Comment: @CR241 No one destroyed your question. Your question is broad since you are asking too many questions and all these questions can easily be found on site.

Comment: I have upvoted your question. Please don't delete a post, if you have a conflict with the fellow user. Your post serves as a good link to the other 3 questions for the future visitors.